# Reflective helper java libraries

Tags: java, reflection, libraries, helper

There are some Java libraries that do stuff you would otherwise have to put in every single class. For example, I had to put a clone() method in every single class until I discovered [Cloner](http://robust-it.co.uk/clone/), and I had to put XML handling code until I discovered [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Are there any more similar helper libraries like these?

Comment: new link for Cloner library: http://code.google.com/p/cloning/

Comment: new link for Cloner library: https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning

Answer (score 4):

You might like [**reflections**](http://code.google.com/p/reflections)

> Reflections scans your classpath, indexes the metadata, allows you to query it on runtime and may save and collect that information for many modules within your project.

Comment: which is better reflections or Apache Commons BeanUtils?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) provides a number of reflection based operations such as the BeanComparator

Comment: which is better reflections or Apache Commons BeanUtils?